# DateTime.TryParseExact Unable to Match Format

Tags: c#, datetime, tryparse

I tried to `TryParseExact` of a date time string but it always does not recognize, and returns `false` instead.

May I know where I could have possibly gone wrong?

```
public static string ConvertToLocalDateString(string dateTimeString)
{
    dateTimeString = "06/04/2020 16:00:00";

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dateTimeString))
    {
        DateTime localDateTime;
        if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dateTimeString, "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out localDateTime))
        {
            return localDateTime.AddHours(8).ToString("d/MMM/yyyy");
        }
    }

    return ""; //returns here
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "returns null". The return value or `TryParseExact` is a bool, so it cannot be `null`.

Comment: apologies for the confusion. I have updated my post, it returns `""`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format for hours in 24h format is "HH", not "hh", so replace "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss" by "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"